# java.lang.NumberFormatException when converting a Hex String to Int

Tags: java

I want to convert a Hex String to decimal, but I got an error in the following code:

```
String hexValue = "23e90b831b74";       
int i = Integer.parseInt(hexValue, 16);
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23e90b831b74"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`23e90b831b74` is too large to fit in an `int`.

You can easily see that by counting the digits. Each two digits in a hex number requires a single byte, so 12 digits require 6 bytes, while an `int` only has 4 bytes.

Use `Long.parseLong`.

```
String hexValue = "23e90b831b74";       
long l = Long.parseLong(hexValue, 16);
```